# Multiple plots in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a combined data set of 8826 Obs and 4 variables. My column names are tVec , yVec, tVec, yVec.

I need to plot the 2 yVec against the x axis as single tVec with legends. I tried the below but plots only one plot.

`plotnew <- ggplot(data=combined, aes(x=tVec, y= yVec, colour='variable')) + geom_line()`

Plot looks like this:
[image: Plot looks like this]

Any ides on this. Have tired many examples. Just not getting it right.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show your data?. You may need to clean your data before plotting.

Comment: Yeah, make your variable/column names distinct, if they are in fact 2 completely different variables.

Comment: Column names not unique ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your input data.frame:

```
combined = data.frame(tVec=1:100,yVec=rnorm(100),tVec=101:200,yVec=rnorm(100))

df = rbind(data.frame(x=combined$tVec,y=combined$yVec,label="first"),
           data.frame(x=combined$tVec.1,y=combined$yVec.1,label="second"))

library(ggplot2)
plotnew <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y, colour=label))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Or

```
df = rbind(data.frame(x=combined$tVec,y=combined$yVec,label="first"),
           data.frame(x=combined$tVec,y=combined$yVec.1,label="second"))

library(ggplot2)
plotnew <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y, colour=label))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Hope that help